# To subtract a vector of values in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

Please is there a matlab code to subtract two vector values where one value is always the larger?

Eg;

```
A=[10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]; B=[5 4 3 2 1 10 9 8 7 6];
```

I want to subtract these two vectors where the minuend is always the larger so that the answer will be:

```
[5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code: `abs(A-B)`

Comment: No question to reframe. It works. Sorry for late post.